# YUI Rich Text Editor and same origin policy in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm experimenting with YUI 3 Rich Text Editor and came across an incident that I don't understand:

when I inject an iframe from different origin inside the editable area, then the content of this iframe can be edited as any other content. I can put the cursor into the iframe area and for example delete characters.

This happens only in Chrome, with Firefox it's not possible to edit the iframe. How is it possible that the DOM of the inner iframe can be manipulated although it's not of the same origin as the page of YUI Text Editor?

Here is the example coding:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <script>
     YUI().use('editor-base', function(Y) {
       var editor = new Y.EditorBase({content: '<strong>This is <em>a test</em></strong><strong>This is <em>a test</em></strong> '});
       //Add the BiDi plugin
       editor.plug(Y.Plugin.EditorBidi);
       //Focusing the Editor when the frame is ready..
       editor.on('frame:ready', function() {this.focus();});
       //Rendering the Editor.
       editor.render('#editor');
     });
    </script>
    <script>
     function inject() {
       var ifr = $('<iframe/>', {
         style: 'display: block; width: 300px; heigth: 200px;',
         src: 'http://demo.yarkon.de',
         frameBorder: 0, 
         scrolling: 'no'
       });
       $('#editor').find('iframe').contents().find('body').append(ifr);
     }
    </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick='inject()'>Inject</button>
    <div id="editor"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Google Chrome 20: iframe is editable

Firefox 13: iframe not editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI Rich Text Editor creates an iframe for the editable area and sets the **designMode** of the document to **on**. That means this iframe and all of its descendants are in editable mode. If you inject then another iframe into the editable area it will inherit this property and be also editable, independent of its origin.

Therefore the assumption that the YUI Text Editor is somehow manipulating the DOM of the injected iframe is not correct: there is no JavaScript involved, it's purely a user interaction like on any other editable field (like textarea or elements with contenteditable attribute).